# MySQL error comparing dates

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to query my database and return with entries that are within a certain date range. As a possible simple example consider the following:

```
@foos = FooTracking.where('when > ?', DateTime.new(2008, 12, 22, 14, 30))
```

Which causes an error and dumps:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
the right syntax to use near 'when >= '2008-12-22 14:30:00')' at line 1:
SELECT `foo_tracking`.* FROM `foo_tracking` WHERE (when >= '2008-12-22 14:30:00')
```

The where call works on other columns of my table (none that have anything to do with dates), what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WHEN` is a SQL reserved word. You can still use it as a column name if you always mention it in backticks like this: `` `when` ``.

Comment: Like: @foos = FooTracking.where(''when' > ?', DateTime.new(2008, 12, 22, 14, 30))?

Comment: Oh wait no, you mean the accent mark in tilda. Totally did the trick, thanks!

Comment: he should just rename the column, that's definitely going to bite him again in the future

Comment: Yes, I really would suggest renaming the column, especially if you're using a database abstraction layer that is building queries for you. You might not always be able to manually insert backtics like that.

Comment: Oops, I guess that non-reaction by the check mark was just it taking a while to check. Had clicked it twice heh.